# What will be the multiplicative inverse of square root of 5 with respect to a natural number $M$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

Can such a number $N$ be found such that $\sqrt{5}N \equiv 1 \mod M$?
If no,what can be the best approximation for $N$?

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{5}$ in this context?  Are you making any assumptions on $M$?  For some values of $M$, there will not be any element $x\in\mathbb{Z}/M\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^2=5$; in others, there may not be a unique choice.

Comment: That depends on some assumptions and the values of $M$ and $N$. If you define $\sqrt{5}$ as a (possible not unique) entity $R_5$ with $R_5^2 \equiv 5 \bmod M$, i.e. 5 is a quadratic residue $\bmod M$, then you have to solve $R_5 N \equiv 1 \bmod M$. An example with $M=19$. Then $\sqrt{5}=R_5\equiv 9 \bmod 19$ (because $9^2=81= 4\times19 + 5$) and $(\sqrt{5})^{-1}=9^{-1} \equiv 17 \bmod 19$.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted in the comments and responses, it all depends on what you mean by the square root of 5. It is, obviously, one of the numbers which, if you square them, equal $5$, but you haven't made it clear whether the squaring is modulo $M$ or not.

- Saxifrage assumes that you are dealing with real numbers (well, algebraic ones) throughout, and produces an heroic series of increasingly close approximations.
- For me (and for some of the commenters) a modular square root of $5$ is an integer which, when squared modulo $N$, equals $5$. This depends on $N$: there is no square root for $N=3, 7, 13, 17$. For $N=2$, the square root is 1; for 5, it is 0; for 11, it is 4 or 7; for 19, it is 9 or 10.

The second interpretation seems to us to be more natural but then you talk about approximations, which leaves us completely confused because approximation is rarely a useful concept in modular arithmetic.